# how to extract data from a json file into table using sql query

Tags: json, sql-server, create-table

How can I import data from JSON file into a table using SQL? I have a problem while using SQL that I am not able to read "value" "key" as they are reserved word.

Here is part of the SQL query and part of the JSON file:

```html
DECLARE @JSON_table VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @JSON_table = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\dbjx1038\Desktop\sql\inventory.json', SINGLE_CLOB) import

SELECT ISJSON(@JSON_table) 
SELECT @JSON_table AS 'JSON Text'

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON_table)

SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON_table, '$.header.columns') 
     WITH (title VARCHAR(50),
           [property] VARCHAR(50),
           minWidth int,
           dataType VARCHAR(50),
           hideable VARCHAR(10))

SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON_table, '$.header.fields')
     WITH (property VARCHAR(50),
           dataType VARCHAR(50),
           display VARCHAR(50))

SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON_table, '$.data')
     WITH (deviceType VARCHAR(50),
           validity VARCHAR(50),
           chasisNumber NVARCHAR(50),
           serialNumber NVARCHAR(50))
```

```js
{
    "columns": [
      {
        "title": "Impacted Entities",
        "property": "values_short_display",
        "minWidth": 250,
        "dataType": "jsonArray"
      },
      {
        "title": "Impacted Entities Details",
        "property": "values",
        "hideable": true,
        "visible": false,
        "minWidth": 250,
        "dataType": "jsonArray"
      },
      {
        "title": "Severity",
        "property": "severity",
        "display": "iconAndText",
        "iconProperty": "severity",
        "hideable": false,
        "icon": [
          {
            "key": "Minor",
            "value": "images/event_minor.png"
          },
          {
            "key": "Medium",
            "value": "images/event_other.png"
          }
        ],
        "minWidth": 70,
        "dataType": "string"
      },
      {
        "title": "Alarm Name",
        "property": "rule_name_display",
        "hideable": false,
        "minWidth": 160,
        "dataType": "string"
      },
      {
        "title": "Cleared Date & Time",
        "property": "cleared_time",
        "displayFormat": "DD MMM YYYY h:mm:ss A z",
        "inputFormat": "unix-time",
        "minWidth": 200,
        "dataType": "date"
      }
    ],
    "fields": [
      {
        "property": "values_short_display",
        "dataType": "jsonArray"
      },
      {
        "property": "uuid",
        "dataType": "string"
      },
      {
        "property": "cleared_by",
        "dataType": "string"
      }
    ],
```

I want to make table that contains this data in columns and how can I read an item "entry_time' as the dash causes an error

Comment: JSON support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: using sql_server

Answer (score 0):

As to the first part of your question, here is how to extract the values for `key` and `value`...

```sql
select title, [property], display, iconProperty, hideable, minWidth, dataType, [key], [value]
from openjson(@JSON_table, '$.header.columns') with (
  title varchar(50),
  [property] varchar(50),
  display varchar(50),
  iconProperty varchar(50),
  hideable bit,
  icon nvarchar(max) as json, --<<-- NOTE: *N*varchar(max) as json
  minWidth int,
  dataType varchar(50)
) j
outer apply openjson(icon) with (
  [key] varchar(50),
  [value] varchar(100)
) i;
```

Note that this returns two rows for `Severity` because its `icon` contains `Minor` and `Medium` keys:

| title | property | display | iconProperty | hideable | minWidth | dataType | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Impacted Entities | values_short_display |  |  |  | 250 | jsonArray |  |  |
| Impacted Entities Details | values |  |  | True | 250 | jsonArray |  |  |
| Severity | severity | iconAndText | severity | False | 70 | string | Minor | images/event_minor.png |
| Severity | severity | iconAndText | severity | False | 70 | string | Medium | images/event_other.png |
| Alarm Name | rule_name_display |  |  | False | 160 | string |  |  |
| Cleared Date & Time | cleared_time |  |  |  | 200 | date |  |  |

Comment: thanks , but how can i extract the data from the "header.fields" and put it in the same table ?