# Load JSON data obtained from a column of a CSV to populate a table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, csv

I am having problems when loading data that is in JSON in a table using SQL Server.

I have the following row from a file in CSV:

```
A: 15957
B: test_category_labeling_highlight_fordham_bbbbb
C: 116
D: 3864
E: 1
F: Policy Change
G: {"Change Type": {"selectedText": "Privacy Policy Last modified: June 30, 2015 (view archived versions)", "startIndexInSegment": 0, "endIndexInSegment": 79, "value": "Unspecified"} , "User Choice": {"selectedText": "Privacy Policy Last modified: June 30, 2015 (view archived versions)", "startIndexInSegment": 0, "endIndexInSegment": 79, "value": "Unspecified"}, " Notification Type ": {" selectedText ":" Privacy Policy Last modified: June 30, 2015 (view archived versions) "," startIndexInSegment ": 0," endIndexInSegment ": 79," value ":" General notice in privacy policy "} }
H: 6/30/15
I: https://www. google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/
```

of which I am interested in columns G, H, I.

To load the data use

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable1
(
    a VARCHAR(max),
    b VARCHAR(max),
    c VARCHAR(max),
    d VARCHAR(max),
    e VARCHAR(max),
    f VARCHAR(max),
    g VARCHAR(max),
    h VARCHAR(max),
    i VARCHAR(max),
);

BULK INSERT #tempTable1
FROM 'C:\Users\file.csv'
WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIRSTROW = 2);

ALTER TABLE #tempTable1 
    DROP COLUMN a, b, c, d, e, f, h, i;
```

So far it does good for me, and I get a column with cells of JSON values ​​{...} in each row.

And now, I would have to somehow reconvert that generated table. The values ​​of columns h and I are the same, and only the JSON changes. To declare said JSON in a temporary variable I had tried

```
DECLARE @json varchar (max);

SELECT g INTO @json FROM #tempTable1;
```

but without success to later access its key values ​​with

```
INSERT INTO Data (G_1, G_2, E, F)
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
    WITH (
          G_1 VARCHAR(50) '$."Personal Information Type".value',
          G_2 VARCHAR(100) '$."Purpose".value'
         );
```

Comment: Perhaps your JSON example data is incomplete - it doesn't include keys for `Purpose` nor `Personal Information Type`.

Comment: Also the JSON paths used in your `openjson()` aren't formatted correctly. They'd need to be `'$."Personal Information Type".value'` and `'$.Purpose.value'`, assuming those keys existed.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have not yet reached that area, since the error really gives me in the line of
DECLARE <at>json VARCHAR(max);

SELECT g INTO <at>json FROM #tempTable1;

when filling the <at>json with the rows of that column to later operate with the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you're dropping the columns in `#tempTable1`, especially when you reference columns `e` and `f` in your `insert into Data` statement further on:

```sql
ALTER TABLE #tempTable1 
    DROP COLUMN a, b, c, d, e, f, h, i;
```

If the following were correct syntax it would still only select the value of `g` for a single row:

```sql
DECLARE @json varchar (max);
SELECT g INTO @json FROM #tempTable1;
```

Instead of trying to operate on the `@json` value try operating on the data in `#tempTable1` directly using something like the following:

```sql
insert into Data (G_1, G_2, E, F)
  select G_1, G_2, E, F
  from #tempTable1
  cross apply openjson(g) with (
    G_1 varchar(50) '$."Personal Information Type".value',
    G_2 varchar(100) '$."Purpose".value'
  );
```

Comment: One last question. If by any chance a key has several items, that is, for example "Change Type": ["one", "two", "three"], how could I access each of those items and insert it in different boards? Until now what I had done was a counter and a while loop, accessing it as $."Change Type"[@count]

Comment: You might want to ask a different question for that, but it would be something similar to `cross apply openjson(g, '$."Change Type"') with (ChangeType nvarchar(10) '$')`.

Comment: That partially serves me, because if I want to access the rest of the key elements that are not the elements that are in that path, I cannot

Comment: You're not limited to a single `openjson()` call. You can stack as many `cross apply` (if one or more matches) or `outer apply` (if zero or more matches) as you need. Here's an example from a [different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67547940/390122) I answered yesterday.

Comment: The response of the link of several cross apply has worked for me, but I run it 6 times and I don't know why. I have 3 items such as `"Change Type": ["one", "two", "three"]` and in total I would have to enter 3 values (rows in the table) and it does it 18 times (rows). It seems strange to me because I don't know where the number 6 comes from

Comment: You should really ask a different question about that. Comments aren't the place to trash out issues without example schema, data and code. Upon seeing your question somebody else might have an even better idea that hasn't yet been considered.